# Garabage collection - Responsiveness

Tags: c++, c, garbage-collection

One week ago my professor talked about garbage collection and its responsiveness. Basically he said that if you use garbage collection you will always have a very small delay before the code will be executed.

Now you can say that the user will not recognize the delay because it is very small.

I am working on a game engine for my final bachelor exam and I am currently deciding which scripting language I will choose for my engine.

---

Now I have the following situation. 
Lets say you create a game with a first person camera. And let's also say that the gamelogic is written in a language with a garbage collection.

**Wouldn't this imply that the user will encounter more input lag than playing a game where the gamelogic is written in a language without garbage collection?**

Now input lag is very difficult to predict because there are so many systems that will produce a delay.

for example `input -> gamecode executing ->  graphics rendering -> rendering on the screen`.

**Is it roughly predictable how much delay I will have If I use a language with gc vs a language without gc?**  `<1ms, <10ms <100ms`

Comment: whoa nelly this is a loaded one. I would say for your purposes, GCing is not going to make a huge difference. Even if you used a language like C your program still needs to take time to free memory when you do `free`. Its not like its instantaneous in any language."

Comment: expanding upon thatidiotguys answer, it also depends on the GC scheme used by the language. Reference counting, for instance, tends to be faster than mark and sweep (roughky speaking).

Comment: "you will always have a very small delay before the code will be executed" probably he was confusing GC with JIT-compilation...

Comment: Your professors explanation is so incredibly inadequate. GC makes it so memory isn't always freed as soon as it could be, it doesn't cause any delay in when code is executed.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes probably because jit and gc are often used together. How much delay will I get with a jit compiler?(generally speaking) <1ms , <10ms <100ms or completely unpredictable?

Comment: you can measure these things on specific machines in specific implementations for your specific program, but I don't believe you can  make a general statement about it.

Comment: well, choice of a **scripting language** may have much larger impact on your performance than any garbage collection...  ...besides, memory allocation (chunks/from a pool vs a lot of small pieces) may have just as big an impact as gc.  That being said, coming from C/C++, I still strongly prefer deterministic memory-handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "scary" things about GC is that (1) it may "feel" slower because it cleans up many objects at once, instead of bothering to do it one-by-one as the code progresses, the way you'd do with manual memory management and that (2) it's non-deterministic, which makes it somewhat unpredictable (but not as terribly as it might sound).

Other than GC happens at specific moments, so it does not make your code "constantly" slower. In fact, I'd say that the program becomes a little faster when it's not in GC, because outside GC it doesn't bother to clean up objects like it would (and should) in non-GC languages, while the memory management mechanism behind GC usually implies that allocation is a little faster than what it is in non-GC languages.